# render pdf from memorystream

Tags: winforms, pdf, memorystream

I have searched for entire day for a solution, but somehow I couldn't find it.
What I wanted is to get data from database (binary file such as PDF) into MemoryStream (which I succeeded to do so), but problem is when I wish to preview that file into WebBrowser control.

so the code goes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

namespace MemoryStreamTest
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream();
    //byte[] temp;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      memory = GetBlobFile();
    }
    private MemoryStream GetBlobFile()
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        string SQL = "SELECT [SnapshotPDF] FROM [DBtest].[dbo].[SamplePDF] WHERE id = " + 21;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=database;Initial Catalog=DBtest; User ID=test; Password=test;");
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(SQL, conn);
        conn.Open();
        byte [] result = (byte[])comm.ExecuteScalar();
        conn.Close();
        if (result != null)
        {
            ms.Write(result, 0, result.Length);
            ms.Position = 0;
        }
        return ms;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //webBrowser1.DocumentText = "application/pdf";
        webBrowser1.DocumentStream = memory; 
    }
}
}
```

[image: PDF render]

Actually webBrowser really output content from memory, but obviously from picture above it's rendered as text...
How can I force to render as PDF?

If it is not possible to use webBrowser control, is there any other controls that I can use in WinForms that would preview/render PDF from memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement an async pluggable protocol, e.g. IClassFactory, IInternetProtocol... Then you use CoInternetGetSession to register your protocol. When IE calls your implementation, you can serve your image data from memory/provide mime type.

It's a bit tedious, but doable. Look at IInternetProtocol and pluggable protocols documentation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767743%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this is a copy of one similar thread, butI'm not that experienced so I don't know how to implement that...

Comment: it is implemented here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6120/A-Simple-protocol-to-view-aspx-pages-without-IIS-i

Comment: I will try to implement  tomorrow, even though I saw that this related with ASP, so I haven't saw connection since I'm using WinForms.

Comment: Thank you for the link but I really don't have a clue what to do with it... is there any other options that I could use to force webBrowser to render memoryStream output?

Comment: what if you try this one ?
http://habjan.blogspot.com/2013/09/how-to-use-ghostscriptnet-library-to.html
and this one  http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/hirendra_singh/how-to-show-pdf-file-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: for the first one, I heard about ghostscript but never used it, second one is a COM of adobeReader and (if I'm correct) it uses Load method which deals with physical file on filesystem, not memorystream from your memory, so second one is not an option. I could instead use webBrowser1.Navigate(); which do exact thing as acrobat control.

Comment: The ghostscript is converting pdf to image, bitmap which is acceptable to me, but when I download his application, and src code, and opened PDF file with his app, I got: **An error occured when call to 'gsapi_init_with_args' is made: -15**

I'm not sure if this application works or not...

Comment: OK installation of gs from site [link](http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html)
did the trick, but reading from memory is still no go...

Comment: @dovla091: application works, -15 means rangecheck error

Answer (score 0):

Done, I found one little bug which I correct it. this is entire code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using Ghostscript.NET;
using Ghostscript.NET.Viewer;

namespace MemoryStreamTest
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    Stream stream;
    byte[] result;
    private GhostscriptViewer _viewer;
    private GhostscriptVersionInfo _gsVersion = GhostscriptVersionInfo.GetLastInstalledVersion();
    private Bitmap _pdfPage = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pictureBox1.Width = 100;
        pictureBox1.Height = 100;
        _viewer = new GhostscriptViewer();
        _viewer.DisplaySize += new GhostscriptViewerViewEventHandler(_viewer_DisplaySize);
        _viewer.DisplayUpdate += new GhostscriptViewerViewEventHandler(_viewer_DisplayUpdate);
        _viewer.DisplayPage += new GhostscriptViewerViewEventHandler(_viewer_DisplayPage);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetBlobFile();
    }
    private void GetBlobFile()
    {
        string SQL = "SELECT [SnapshotPDF] FROM [test].[dbo].[InvoiceAdded] WHERE id = " + 21;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=test;Initial Catalog=test; User ID=test; Password=test;");
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(SQL, conn);
        conn.Open();
        result = (byte[])comm.ExecuteScalar();
        conn.Close();
        stream = new MemoryStream(result);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ConvertToBitmap();
    }

    private void ConvertToBitmap()
    {
        _viewer.Open(stream, _gsVersion, true);    
    }
    //DisplayPage
    void _viewer_DisplayPage(object sender, GhostscriptViewerViewEventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        pictureBox1.Update();
    }
    //DisplaySize - dynamically
    void _viewer_DisplaySize(object sender, GhostscriptViewerViewEventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = e.Image;
    }
    //DisplayUpdate - automatic update picture
    void _viewer_DisplayUpdate(object sender, GhostscriptViewerViewEventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        pictureBox1.Update();
    }
}
}
```

keep in mind that for this I needed to add .dll from Ghostscript.NET (a nice wrapper made by my patriot from Croatia), also I needed to install Ghostscript interpreter from [GhostScript interpreter](http://habjan.blogspot.com/2013/09/how-to-use-ghostscriptnet-library-to.html)

And also many thanks to user:  sm.abdullah

which actually point me to right direction.
Cheers

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution with everyone. I would also recommend to use the latest Ghostscript.NET library which can be found here: http://github.com/jhabjan/Ghostscript.NET